# Show an element and hide it after 1 second

Tags: jquery

I have the following element:

```
<div class="text hide">Hello SO</div>
```

I show it with jQuery like this:

```
$('.text').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
```

So my `<div>` is show.

I want now it fade to hide again after 1 second.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **[`delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay)** and use **[`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show)** to show the item and **[`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide)** to hide the item

```
$('.text').show(1).delay(1000).hide(1);
```

***Note :*** You need to set duration for `show()` and `hide()` to work the `deley()`

Comment: After using your line, my <div> stay hide.

Comment: @user3396984 - Doesn't work unless you pass a duration as argument

Comment: It works. It was due with .hide{display:none !important}

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [jquery.animate()](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) function. The third argument is the time that the animation takes.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 1):

You can show the text first then use setTimeout to hide it in 1000ms:

```
var text = $('.text');
text.show();
setTimeout(function(){
   text.hide();
}, 1000);
```