# How to trigger an element to hide using php

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4, alert

I have the following php codes that echo an alert.

```
echo '<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" id = "noOperator" role="alert" >
      <strong>Not certified! </strong>'.$checkBoxValue.' is not certified to use '.$needleType.'
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>';
```

But I want to close this alert after it showed. Thus I gave the following as echo again.

```
echo ' <script>
      $("#noOperator").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
           $("#noOperator").slideUp(500);
      });
       </script>';
```

But it is not working

Does anyone knows why?

Comment: **never** mix PHP and JS - they're different langauges on different sides. Client-side and server-side get executed differently and thus, can result in unexpected behaviour. Use AJAX to pass PHP and JS

Comment: You can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22283698/show-an-element-and-hide-it-after-1-second

Comment: Before downvoting, can someone tell me, why my code is not working? By right it should work right? I want to know why it is not working. I am not asking the best practice, instead trying to understand why it is not working

Comment: @little_coder Thanks for showing something. But somehow its not working for my case. And like i mentioned, I would like to know why my code is not working even though my logic seems right.

Comment: The question is how can we trigger the element to hide using php?

Comment: Why not use pure jquery without php?

Comment: I know Ajax is the solution to this. Although this code is not best practice, I still want to know why it isn't working. It is quite easy to say this is not the practice and advice to use ajax. But it is more interesting to know why this code is not working although logic is correct

Comment: @little_coder don't be confused, jQuery isn't pure - it's a JavaScript library that requires including - which can affect performance, but yeah is not "pure jquery"

Comment: @treybake well you are right. But what I meant by that regarding to what the OP was asking, was he may use JQuery or Javascript without echoing the code with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use JQuery without echoing the code using PHP. And detect the element if its visible to trigger the hide function. Or just use the close button of the alert box.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  if ($("#noOperator").is(":visible")) {
    //$('#noOperator').hide();
     $("#noOperator").animate({
        'margin-top' : "-50%",
        'opacity' : '0',
        'visibility' : 'hide'
      },1000);
   
    console.log("hiding now")
  }
  
}, 1000); // hide the element if visible after 1 second


//or just use the button on the alert box
//if you want it just uncomment below

//$('.close').click(function(){
//    $('#noOperator').hide();
//});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" id="noOperator" role="alert">
  <strong>Not certified! </strong>
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
</div>
```

> Your code will work if you change it to:

```
echo '<script>
         setTimeout(function() {
            $("#noOperator").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
              $("#noOperator").slideUp(500);
            });
         }, 3000);
      </script>';
```

Comment: This is perfectly working fine. Its hiding abruptly. But I am not getting the animation effect of slide up, fade etc.

Comment: @Anu Just change `hide()` to `slideUp()` or `fade()`

Comment: @Anu I updated my answer. Please check it. I used animate to add some smooth transition, then added visibility hidden to hide the element.

Comment: Thank you. It is working. I marked this as answer. But I still wonder why my initial code is not working. It supposed to do the same

Comment: @Anu Try to add set timeout on your code. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that earlier. But it didn't work. I think it got something to do with the fadeTo, slideUp etc. It might not work well with php. By the way you might be little coder. But you are so helpful.

Comment: Try to change the setTimeout to 2 secs `2000` or 3 seconds OR change it to `$(window).load(function() {setTimeout(function() {
            $("#noOperator").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
              $("#noOperator").slideUp(500);
            });
         }, 1000);})`. If that won't work, just echo animate function that I added earlier. Cheers!